# redirect to another page using onsubmit or action?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to direct to another page on particular event occurrence ...This is my code..but it does not direct to another page but the JavaScript code works...

```
<form class="list-group-item"  method="get" onsubmit="action='Search.jsp'; myFunction('name');return false;"  >
  <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<%=1%>"> 
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-fw "></i> <span onsubmit="action='Search.jsp'" onclick="action='Search.jsp';document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';setValue('Subject')"  style="margin-left:1%">Subject </span>    
  <span class=" text-muted small"  onclick="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';setValue('Subject And')"  style="margin-left:40%"><em> And <i class="fa  fa-angle-down "></i></em>
  </span>
</form>
```

First I tried action="search.jsp" outside onsubmit but that didn't work..I am new to all this and I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Add an button inside `<form>` tag

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Add **action** attribute in form tag

```
action="Search.jsp"
```

Whenever you click `Submit` button, the page will be redirected to `Search.jsp`

Comment: First I tried action="search.jsp" outside onsbmit but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to submit the form

Answer (score 1):

1) If you simply want to get it redirected to **`Search.jsp`** after form submission, remove all crap JS code from your form and add a simple **`action`** attribute in **`form tag`**.
2) **`Action attribute`** behaves as redirect if you submit the form.
3) Writing JS code within HTML Tags is a bad convention. Always write JS code within **`<script>..</script>`** blocks or a different **`JS file`** and then include it.

```
<form class="list-group-item" method="get" action="Search.jsp"  >
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<%=1%>">
    ...
    ...
</form>
```

**OR**

You can **`ajaxify`** your code (meaning submit the form through ajax and then redirect).

```
<form class="list-group-item" method="get" action="Search.jsp" name="search" >
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<%=1%>">
    ...
    ...
</form>

<script>
$(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    $("form:[name='search']").on("submit", function(){
        var form = $(this);
        var data = form.serialize();
        var action = form.attr("action");

        $.get(action, data)
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply *`return true`* from the `myFunction` and use *`<input type="submit">`* to submit the form.

Sample code: (*read inline comments*)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        /* return false in case of validation fail */
        alert("Hi");
        return true;
    }
</script>

<form class="list-group-item" action="Search.jsp" method="get"
      onsubmit="return myFunction()">
    <!-- other fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```